# Back-Forward in Google Chrome disabled by internal error Ignoreeventandevict

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, browser-cache

Recently I come accross an issue whereby the Back-Forward Cache in Google Chrome was disabled and using the Back-Forward Cache debug tools revealed the issue was an Internal error `Ignoreeventandevict`. If you do a Google search for the error you'll find almost nothing about the error. I'm posting this question so that if others run into a similar issue they'll hopefully find this post.

The issue for me was that I had a `pagehide` event listener which was making a `history.replaceState` call. Removing the `history.replaceState` call resolved the issue. This isn't documented as-far as I can tell, it'd be nice if Chrome provided a more detail of the error. Note I've not tested this in other browsers to see if they have a similar issue.

I hope this helps anyone struggling with the same `Ignoreeventandevict` error.

[image: Screenshot of the Ignoreeventandevict error in Google Chrome]

Answer (score 1):

The `history.replaceState` call disables the Back-Forward Cache in Google Chrome if used in a `pagehide` handler.